# My vertical navbar is on top of my horizontal navbar even if z-index in bigger using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am having a problem using CSS, I am working with a team on a react project, I am building a Left Menu using react, it is finished but I had one more little problem, is that my Left Menu is on the top of the main Menu of the web page, I will explain more with images, 
Here is what I have when I first open the webpage :

[image]

But when I scroll down That what I see :

[image]

But That is not what I want, what I want that is the horizontal nav is in the top, like this : [image]

The other problem I am having is that I can not modify CSS of the horizontal navbar since I am not the one who made it and I dont know why he set the properties' values the way they are set but here is my SASS file :

( my left Menu SASS file ) :

```
.co-menu-left {

width:100px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
left:10px;

z-index: -10;

transition: 0.4s all ease;

&__ontop {
    top:87px;
}

&__onmiddle {
    top: -128px;
}

&__onbottom {
    top:-275px;
}

}
```

and here is my React Component :

```
class MenuLeft extends Component {


  /* 
   *    Here is some methods and constructor that are not useful in the situation 
  */
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="co-menu">
            <div className={"co-menu-left co-menu-left" + this.state.position}>
                <Grid container>
                    {this.state.contratItems.map(item => (
                        <ContratProposition
                            key={item.id}
                            id={item.id}
                            allContratDeselected={this.allContratDeselected}
                            isSelected={item.isSelected}
                        />
                    ))}
                    <Grid item xs={12} className="pt-0" />
                </Grid>

                {this.renderItems(this.state.menuItems)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default MenuLeft;
```

So as you can see I set my z-index to a negative value so that my LeftMenu can be in the bottom, because when I inspected the horizontal navbar ( white ) I can see that :

[image]

What I thought is that if I set my z-index value to a value less that 10 then everything will be fine, but that seems like to not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the style of the base `.co-main-container.co-modal-ui-container` element (not the `::before` pseudo-element)?